# Form contents layout in email

Tags: php, email

Wonder if anyone could give me a bit of advice with PHP for displaying the content in the email?

Currently the form data is displayed one line directly below the other, and as the forms are large, it is very hard to read.

How do I get a line in between so it looks like this?

```
NAME

EMAIL

ETC.
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
function IsInjected($str)
{
$injections = array(
       '(\t+)',
       '(%08+)',
       '(%09+)'
       );

$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";

if(preg_match($inject,$str))
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
}

function processText($text) {
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = trim($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
return $text;
}

$formname=$_POST['formname'];
$spamcode=$_POST['spam_preventer_code'];

switch ($formname) {
    case 0: $to='someone@email.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=42;
        $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
    case 1: $to='someone@email.com';
        $spamcodecheck=42;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
    case 3: $to='someone@email.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=42;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
    case 4: $to='someone@email.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=73;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
        case 5: $to='someone@email.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=48;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
        case 6: $to='someone@email.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=64;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
        case 7: $to='someone@email.org.uk';
        $spamcodecheck=48;
                    $thankyoupage="thankyou.htm";
        break;
}



if (!empty($to)) { 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($spamcode==$spamcodecheck) {
        $message="Form Contents \n\n";
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if(!IsInjected($value)) $message=$message.$key."=".processText($value)."]\n";
        }

        $subject = "Form $formname submission";
        mail($to,$subject,$message);
        //echo "Mail Sent. Thank you, we will contact you shortly.";
        $header="Location: $thankyoupage";
            header($header); 
    } else {
        echo "Bad Spam Code, please go back and try again.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No form submit in post data";
}
} else {
echo "Bad Form Name.";
}

?>
```

Comment: this is something you have to change the mime type of header.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to double-space by including an extra newline character `\n` when assembling your fields.

Instead of this:

```
if(!IsInjected($value)) $message=$message.$key."=".processText($value)."]\n";
```

Use this:

```
if(!IsInjected($value)) $message=$message.$key."=".processText($value)."]\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Supports HTML Email as you need. Its mainly depends on your Content Type.

Refer to understand the Message Content Type:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_email#Multi-part_formats

PHP Library to send Custom HTML Email:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

```
$to = 'tracey@so.com';

$subject = 'Your Custom HTML Format Email';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['from-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['reply-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: sender@so.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table>';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td>Name</td>';
$message .= '<td>John</td>';    
$message .= '</tr>';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td>Email</td>';
$message .= '<td>John@site.com</td>';       
$message .= '</tr>';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td>Etc</td>';
$message .= '<td>etc . . </td>';        
$message .= '</tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```